# Howto play video with external audio in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, video, audio, synchronization, external

Is there any proper method to play synchronously video and external audio, other than simply having two MediaElement (one for video source and one for audio) started simultaneously? I need to play video with different soundtracks, but I belive that just two separated MediaElements will be out of sync at some point of time. Maybe there is some way to add audio source to the existing MediaElement with video?
Platform: SL3, but SL4 will be good as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This project provides "support for multiple audio tracks" which sounds like it will do what you want:  http://smf.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have already saw this project, but according to their description "customizable media player for IIS Smooth Streaming delivery" and documentation they use IIS that is not my case - I don't have it on the server side.

Comment: Fair enough.  All the cleverness in IIS Smooth Streaming is client-side though, so you might find it works without.